# FirebaseMessagingService is working very slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `FirebaseMessagingService` to send push notification but intially it works properly but after some time receivers receive notification very late

Answer (score 1):

When someone receives a messege is more depending on the recivers device, os and battery status. As soon as you send the messages to the messaging service your work is done. Maybe you are testing on a device with low battery status, older os or other context that slows down the messaging delivery. If you don't delay to send the message to FCM there is not much you can do anyway.